# How to differentiate the html element based on the background image used using python?

Tags: python

I have a scenario where I need to differentiate my next stop based on background image found in my id "t44_0_1". If I have the first  tag then I need to print "OK" else "Not OK".
Anyone who can help to solve this?

```html
<div id="t44_0_1" class="ah" style="left:18px;top:0px;width:16px;height:16px;background-image: url('SMG?q=1&amp;i=0191f5aaded042c33180d357113667fbefc81b95&amp;w=16&amp;h=16');"></div>

<div id="t44_0_1" class="ah" style="left:34px;top:0px;width:16px;height:16px;background-image: url('SMG?q=1&amp;i=be90bfe1cf3196f2afc7abf4393e6f30be367d75&amp;w=16&amp;h=16');"></div>
```

Comment: What is a "stop" in this context? How does your "id" contain background images? What do you mean by the first element, and what would cause you to have or not have it? I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. My best guess is that it has *something* to do with some web page, but I can't even begin to guess which one.

Comment: I see part of the problem: `'''` quotes will not work on Stack Overflow for HTML tags. You need to use code formatting, which I have fixed for you.

Comment: This is my first time posting a question so did some mistakes please find the edited post

Comment: Okay, this way also works. I guess that for one of these `<div>` tags you want to print "OK" and for the other one you want to print "Not OK"? Which is which? What is the rule that tells you this, exactly?  You said something about background images, but what exactly is it about the `background-image: url(...)` part that your code cares about? Also, what exactly are you using to read the HTML in the first place? It may have some tools that can help, depending.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the url in the first <div> has a "Tick" and url in second <div> tag has a "Warning" images. In real time I want to call some other functions instead of printing the statements. Since it is already embedded in the html site in this way I want to know how can I identify it

Comment: So you are looking for exact values like `i=be90bfe1cf3196f2afc7abf4393e6f30be367d75` or `i=0191f5aaded042c33180d357113667fbefc81b95` I guess? Since that is the part that differs between the two `url`s specified for the CSS.

Comment: Yes, how I can I identify them using python?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel any ideas on how I can proceed?